# how to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'poster_path')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am currently working on react.js movie application  project. I am getting this error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'poster_path')  ) . when I was making poster card through TMDB API  I don't know how to solve that error
anyone can explain how to handle it

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./Css/PosterCard.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const PosterCard = ({item}) => {
       
     
   const poster_path = item.poster_path
   ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${item.poster_path}`
   : "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ekZobS8isE6mA53RAiGDG93hBxL.jpg";
   console.log(item);
      
   const detailView_link = item.poster_path
   ? item.release_date
   ? `/movie/${item.id}`
   : `/tvshow/${item.id}`
 : "/tvshow/63174";
 
 console.log(detailView_link);

  return (
    <div className="poster-card-wrapper">
         <Link to={detailView_link}>
      <img src={poster_path} alt="poster" />
      </Link>
  </div>
  );
};

export default PosterCard;
```

I want try to make poster card through API  and how to handle that error

Comment: It looks like `item` is `undefined`. Can you show how you use the `PosterCard` component ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `item` seems to be `undefined`.

Make sure you pass a properly assigned `item` object into your `PosterCard`:

```
<PosterCard item={item} />
```

If I do this with the code you provided, I don't get an error and the image gets displayed on the page.

Check out [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-0nh5mm?file=/index.js) code sandbox for more detail